# RAID won't start at boot

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a problem with a RAID 1 on my Raspberry Pi 2. as system is use jessie-lite.

If I reboot or boot the system, RAID won't start.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
```

How can I get RAID to start at boot?

After `mdadm --assemble --scan`, the RAID will start.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 2 drives.
```

mdadm config

```
mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR ****@******.***

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=287dd2d2:88e06dc7:25dd3aaa:196d016f name=raspberrypi:0

# This configuration was auto-generated on Wed, 30 Nov 2016 12:08:42 +0000 by mkconf
the fstab file

proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
/dev/md0        /mnt/md0        ext4    defaults,nofail         0
```

The mounted devices:

```
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="752385f3" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/mmcblk0p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="boot" UUID="70F7-FA1D" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="752385f3-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: UUID="3598ef8e-09be-47ef-9d01-f24cf61dff1d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="752385f3-02"
/dev/sda: UUID="287dd2d2-88e0-6dc7-25dd-3aaa196d016f" UUID_SUB="6bfd7be2-7a7b-d01e-7813-66cc1d91966e" LABEL="raspberrypi:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/md0: UUID="5831b12b-8bdc-49ef-bdd4-4578d703491b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb: UUID="287dd2d2-88e0-6dc7-25dd-3aaa196d016f" UUID_SUB="60adaf57-72f9-ec6e-8653-331682fdd90d" LABEL="raspberrypi:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
```

If I know reboot the same. RAID is not active

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Are these USB devices? These need some time until they appear, so if the system boot passes through the point where it scans for RAID arrays, they won't be found, and since the RAID is not needed for booting, the initrd doesn't wait for them as it would for e.g. the root filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of an odd setup, I create my RAID1 array and then pass it to a VM. But the following should set you in the right direction.

In my mdadm.conf file is the following to create the ARRAY, the device part tells which disks to look for and the array part says which disks are part of the array and at what level.

```
DEVICE /dev/mmcblk0p[1-9]*
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 devices=/dev/mmcblk0p1,/dev/mmcblk0p2
```

Then make sure that your RAID array is in you `/etc/fstab` file which auto-mounts on boot or whenever you ask it to.

```
/dev/md0   /mnt/md0  ext4  defaults  0 0
```